# ejabberd on shared hosting

Tags: php, ejabberd

Can we install ejabberd chat server on the shared hosting? Or it is necessary to have a virtual hosting server to install it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot install ejabberd on shared hosting as you need Erlang and many component that are usually not available on shared hosting servers.

Comment: OK.. What is the best option if I want to implement a chat solution with a PHP server and clients on iOS and Android?

Comment: Deploy your own platform or buy a service like ejabberd SaaS ?